# Как поменять форму и цвет radiobutton

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет. Мне нужно поменять цвет самого радио баттона и изменить размер.
Если есть возможность, то присвоить функционал переключения картинки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // первый радио баттон нажатие картинка - 2
        {
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("2");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Создайте кастомный контрол, унаследовавшись от радиобаттона и переопредилите `OnPaint`, написав свой собственный код отрисовки.

Comment: class NewRadioButton : RadioButton { protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent) { pevent.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, this.ClientRectangle); if (this.Checked) pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(this.ClientRectangle.X + 1, this.ClientRectangle.Y + 1, this.ClientRectangle.Width - 2, this.ClientRectangle.Height - 2)); } }

Comment: @Blackmeser спасибочки. сейчас буду пробовать